# Integration of polymer and web components for symfony3

Tags: symfony, polymer, symfony3.x

Does anybody know how to use a simple webcomponent in symfony3?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The symfony docs suggest using separate repository or at minimum keeping those resources inside the "web" directory:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html#frontend-based-applications

Comment: thank you for this information.
Did you ever do it?

Comment: I have experimented enough to know that the devs behind Symfony were right? :p Polymer bundler does a better job at compressing/aggregating assets than Assetic - so you are probably better off using those tools on your front end code. The issue I had with 3.3.* was disabling non-essential services (ie: twig, etc). This I believe is a non-issue with 4+ and the flex component.

Comment: Have you tried something? can you give us more details ?